# How to Throw Custom 404 Messages in Python Bottle

Tags: python, bottle

With Python's Bottle framework, I'm trying to catch all 404s and replace the framework's output with my own.

How do I catch all thrown 404s and replace them with my own output?

So far, I've reduced my application to nothing but one that throws 404s, and it still outputs the framework's "Error: 404 Not Found" output instead of "Nothing here, sorry".  My application is below.

```
from bottle import Bottle, error

"""App Instantiation"""
app = application = Bottle()

@error(404)
def error404(error):
    return 'Nothing here, sorry'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `@app.error`.

```
from bottle import Bottle

"""App Instantiation"""
app = application = Bottle()

@app.error(404)  # changed from OP
def error404(error):
    return 'Nothing here, sorry'
```

---

`@error` doesn't bind your `error404` function to your app.  (I believe it just binds it to Bottle's "default" app, which IMO is a somewhat confusing and unnecessary feature.)

Comment: My uwsgi application required the line `app = Bottle()` to be `app = application = Bottle()`.

Comment: Ah, I see--sorry for the confusion.  I'll restore that line in my answer.

Comment: How can you import something called error, then have it defined as a function parameter? Is that a mistake?

Comment: `error` and `app.error` are two different objects. Importing `error` is no longer needed in my example; I left it in to minimize the changes I made from OP's code. But since it's causing confusion, I'll remove it. Thanks.

Comment: `app = bottle.default_app()` should also be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using bottle in version 0.12.13 and the solution above does not (no longer?) work for me. I looked in the [documentation](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#error-pages) and solved it like it's suggested there:

```
from bottle import route, run
from bottle import error
import webbrowser


webbrowser.open("http://localhost:8080/index")


@route("/index")
def index():
    return "<a href='/test'>Next page</a>"


@error(404)
def error404(error):
    return 'Nothing here, sorry'


run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```